# How to center mat-card in angular materials?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a login card that I designed using angular materials, whenever I run it on the page the content sticks to the left of the page.

I tried using `flex` and using `layout-align="center center"` but I still cannot bring the card to the center of the page

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is my html:

```
<mat-card class="example-card" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
  <mat-card-header>
    <div class="login-box-header" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hDqa3p/codershood.png">
    </div>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <form class="example-form">
      <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password"type="password" name="password" required>
        </mat-form-field></td>
      </tr></table>
    </form>
    <mat-spinner [style.display]="showSpinner ? 'block' : 'none'"></mat-spinner>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="login()" color="primary">Login</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

and here is the content still not centered:

[image]

Answer (score 42):

Fixed it by using Very simple Flex

```
.main-div{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

and wrapping everything with a class

```
<!-- Classes main-div and example-card are catagorized in .css file -->
<div class="main-div">

<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <div class="login-box-header">
        <!-- Src image is temporary hosted in image.ibb-->
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hDqa3p/codershood.png">
    </div>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <form class="example-form">
      <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password"type="password" name="password" required>
        </mat-form-field></td>
      </tr></table>
    </form>
    <mat-spinner [style.display]="showSpinner ? 'block' : 'none'"></mat-spinner>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="login()" color="primary">Login</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 12):

Please try below css methods.

1. first way.

```
.example-card{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Then create one cover div for "mat-card". Give a class name for cover div like "mat-card-cvr".

```
.mat-card-cvr{
   width: 100%;
   text-align:center;
}
```

2.second way.

```
.example-card{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
}
```

3. Third way.

```
.example-card{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Then create one cover div for "mat-card". Give a class name for cover div like "mat-card-cvr".

```
.mat-card-cvr{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    line-height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

4. Fourth way.

```
.mat-card-cvr{
    top:50%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
}
    
.example-card{
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: this only center it horizontaly, not verticaly

Comment: You are not mention about vertical align in your question?

Comment: Can you please share your link. I will try my level best.

Comment: i am talking about center in page

Comment: please try fourth way.

Answer (score 4):

Material provided mat-grid-list to arrange rows and columns.
use it like this:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rows="1" rowHeight="2:1">
    <mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-card>
        Your form here
        </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

See docs for more info https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

This did the wonder to me:

```
.btn-center{
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried OP answer but I have to control width too, so had to use div inside div and then mat-card

```
.centering-div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.my-card {
  max-width: 100%;
  color: rgb(63, 81, 181);
}
```