# How to center mat-card on the webpage

Tags: angular

I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800054/how-to-center-mat-card-in-angular-materials) to center my mat-card.  Here is the HTML code:

```
  <body>
     <div class="main-div">
       <mat-card >
```

This is the css file :

```
.main-div{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

The form still spans the width of the page.  I even added "max-width: 400px;' The display does not change.

Comment: try "width: 400px" in the mat-card?

Comment: Thanks @Haijin  I added 'width: 400px' with no effects.

Comment: I created a demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-template-fork-first-rqvhhb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css. It seems working. Let me know if anything is wrong.

Comment: @Haijin thanks it works!

Answer (score 0):

After googling, this worked:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
<mat-card fxFlex> 
  card
</mat-card>
 </div>
```

and

```
mat-card{

  display: block;
 margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;  

}

:host {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```