# Center mat-cards on the window

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-card

I've seen a post on stack overflow kind of answering my question ([How to center mat-card in angular materials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800054/how-to-center-mat-card-in-angular-materials))
but the result is really not perfect (see image). 
[image]

As you can see, the cards get squished, and they're on the same line. No matter the scss I add to the cards, it doesn't affect them. I'd like them to be much bigger, and one on top of the other.
I find it incredible that scss options are not simpler to move your elements where you want...

Comment: FYI, you need to post a [reprex], otherwise we end up guessing what's going on with your code. I can't imagine Sass has anything to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

Add `center` class to mat-card tag and put below css.

```
    .center {
        top   : 20%;
        height: 40%;
        width : 40%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
    }
```

If this is not apply in scss file then put ::ng-deep just prefix of .center

Comment: Ok that's better, they're still next to each other insted of one above the other, but that could do§ don't know why I couldn't change their size prior to that... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer given in the [How to center mat-card in angular materials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800054/how-to-center-mat-card-in-angular-materials), it works

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-fsebr1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)